# Computer becoming unresponsive when changing display

Tags: 14.04, graphics, hardware, external-monitor, toshiba-satellite

I just had a weird issue come up today.  I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 on a Toshiba Satellite laptop with an external monitor.  Until today, everything was working fine, but I started having a problem.  Normally I boot up my computer, plug in the monitor, and hit Fn + F5 a bunch until I get the external-only display with native resolution (the resolution of my external monitor is much higher than my laptop's native resolution).  However, today, instead of migrating the display to the external monitor, instead, the external monitor went blank and I got an unresponsive command prompt on my laptop's main display (i.e. a black screen with the flashing white bar, but I can't type anything and none of the keys do anything).  I'm wondering how I can fix this and go back to using Fn + F5 to set up my display.

I have done some debugging, and here's what I've found:

1) When I go into Display Settings and manually switch the display to external monitor only, it works fine (in fact, that's how I'm writing this post).

2) When I do not have my power cable plugged in, sometimes Fn + F5 will work as before and alternate the display properly, but sometimes it fails.

3) I have tested multiple monitors, and experienced this problem in multiple settings.

Can someone help me debug this issue?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar problems in the past with my Toshiba Laptop which was resolved by installing the proprietary nVidia driver as my laptop had an nVidia GEForce graphic card.

Comment: I have the proprietary ATI driver installed already.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: What happens when you start up with the external monitor connected?

Comment: Previously, it would start up in dual display mode (or stretch display mode, not actually sure, since I changed it immediately upon boot).  Since I manually changed it to single display mode in System Settings, it now boots into single display mode on the external screen.